# 'FBSDKMacros.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk

My podfile has the following dependecies in swift.

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
```

When building the project, an issue is thrown as below:

> Lexical or preprocessor issue
>
> 'FBSDKMacros.h' file not found
>
> FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV3.h

I am new to iOS programming and am not able to identify what the error is about.

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this

Comment: No @Tom Dropped it.